# How to implement cancel action on facebook page tab app

Tags: php, facebook

I am working on a facebook app which is implement with php api . The problem that I face is that when I click cancel it redirects me on the same button which means that I cannot close the dialog at all . I want to find a way when user clicks cancel button to redirect him on fb page of the app. 
Is there any way that I can catch with php the cancel action . I am stuck with this many hours ..
I am providing some code below :

```
if(!$user){
  $loginUrl = '';

  if(isset($signed_request["app_data"])){

    $loginUrl = $this->fb->getLoginUrl(
      array(
          'canvas' => 1,
          'scope' =>'email, user_likes',
          'redirect_uri'=>$curContest->fbpagelink .'?sk=app_'.$curContest->app_id . '?app_data=' . $signed_request["app_data"]
      )
    );
  }else {
    $loginUrl = $this->fb->getLoginUrl(
      array(
          'canvas' => 1,
          'scope' =>'email, user_likes',
          'redirect_uri'=>$curContest->fbpagelink .'?sk=app_'.$curContest->app_id
      )
    );
  }
  /* Redirect the main window NOT the iframe */
  //print_r($_GET['app_data']);
    echo '<script>top.location="'.$loginUrl.'";</script>';
}else{
//code of the app when user click on okay button ...
}
```

Comment: Instead of redirecting the user to the Auth dialog automatically (which is bad practice anyway, since the user should be able to see what your app is about before logging in), you could simple use a link/button, so that they can trigger login themselves.

Answer (score -1):

When user cancels the authorization option, the facebook redirects him back to your application with a 'error' parameter in return url..

so in code you can write

```
if($_GET('error') || $_GET('error_reason')){
   // redirect to your facebook page

}
```

Hope this works for you !!

Comment: yes I know but I cannot access this variable from the app which is in iframe .. I have tried it ..